# Infopath: This form cannot be opened because it requires a domain permission level

Tags: infopath

I have some Infopath forms. The definitions are stored at the server. 
I want to publish the form to a user who doesn't have connectivity to the server. 
When I copy the .xsn file to his computer. It shows this error:
"This form cannot be opened because it requires a domain permission level and it currently has restricted permission. To fix this problem, open the form from the location it was published to."

Comment: Does the form access resources on the domain as the applicable setting describes?

Comment: Then accessing it without a connection to the server means those features won't work, which means the form won't work.

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the InfoPath Form actually uses resources on the server that he doesn't have access to, it's not going to work in its current form.

You would need to do one of the following, in order of what I consider increasing complexity:

A) Get the user connected to the appropriate network, maybe through a VPN if he's remote.

B) Duplicate those resources on a server the user does have access to.

C) Alter the form so that it doesn't require those resources. Maybe put them inside the form.